# How to get a RGB value from Color variable

Tags: java, colors, rgb

```
JColorChooser.showDialog(tEkran, "Select a Color", selectedColorBG);
```

After a choice a colour I need to transfer it to 3 variable. Like this:

```
colorR = selectedColorBG.getR

colorG = selectedColorBG.getG

colorB = selectedColorBG.getB
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Did you bother to look at the documentation before posting this question?  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html

Comment: Did you even look at the Java API? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html#getColor%28%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JColorChooser` has a `getColor` method which returns a `Color` which has methods `getRed`, `getGreen` and `getBlue` respectively

Answer (score 1):

You must process the return value:

```
Color selectedColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(tEkran, "Select the color", initialColor);
int red = selectedColor.getRed();
int green = selectedColor.getGreen();
int blue = selectedColor.getBlue();
```

Answer (score 0):

A look at the [`java.awt.Color` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) would have answered your question:

```
int getAlpha()
    Returns the alpha component in the range 0-255.
int getBlue()
    Returns the blue component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB space.
int getGreen()
    Returns the green component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB space.
int getRed()
    Returns the red component in the range 0-255 in the default sRGB space.
```